# Symbol of Dot inside a circle

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, logic

I am looking for this symbol which I haven't found online (especially with a large dot inside the circle)
.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you already go through [this list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)? Or did you try [this web app](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)?

Comment: This looks vaguely like the `\fisheye` symbol from the `stix` package

Comment: BTW, if any of the answers helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept one of them by clicking on the checkmark symbol.

Answer (score 10):

Build your own...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\eye{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.33pt}%
  {\bullet}{\bigcirc}}}
\newcommand\smallereye{\scalerel*{\eye}{x}}
\begin{document}
x\eye\smallereye
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an alternative

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\eye{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.3pt}%
  {\bullet}{\scriptstyle\bigcirc}}}
\newcommand\smallereye{\scalerel*{\eye}{x}}
\begin{document}
x\eye\smallereye
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The 1st version looks better.

Answer (score 10):

`amssymb` has a `\circledcirc` command which outputs an empty circle inside a bigger circle, but I don't think there's a similar command where the inner circle is filled. You could however start from `\circledcirc` and stack a `\bullet` on it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\circledbullet}{%
    \mathbin{%
        \ooalign{$\circledcirc$\cr\hidewidth$\bullet$\hidewidth}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\( \circledbullet \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add `\mathord{...}` or probably `\mathbin` around the `\ooalign`, to make this only usable in math mode. Your code would have quite unexpected effects if used in text mode. Try embedding it in a paragraph and see. In other words, always have braces (or some other group) around `\ooalign`.

Comment: @egreg I added `\mathbin` to the answer's code. Thanks for the advice, I'm still learning how to properly use `\ooalign`.

Answer (score 10):

As complement, as it's not exactly the fat dot you're looking for.

From unicode:

- ⊙ (U+2299, cicled dot operator)
- ⨀ (U+2A00, n-ary circled dot operator)
- ☉ (U+2609, sun)

From Latex:

- `\odot` [image: solar] usually for the unit solar mass

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588034), I wouldn't use a phonetic symbol. Unsurprisingly, Unicode provides a CIRCLED BULLET symbol (U+29BF). To see the difference, compare the circled bulled (left) with the bilabial click (right) in different fonts.

```
%Use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%http://www.quivira-font.com/
\newfontfamily\quivira{Quivira}
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}
\newfontfamily\notosans{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\notosansmath{Noto Sans Math}
\newfontfamily\charissil{Charis SIL}
\begin{document}
%Circled bullet
\quivira\char"29BF\relax
\symbola\char"29BF\relax
\notosansmath\char"29BF\relax
\quad
%Latin letter bilabial click
\quivira\char"298\relax
\symbola\char"298\relax
\notosans\char"298\relax
\charissil\char"298\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use also the symbol `\faDotCircle[regular]` taken from `fontawesome5` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\newcommand{\cirbd}{\mathrel{\text{\faDotCircle[regular]}}}


\begin{document}
$a\cirbd B$, $A_{\cirbd} B$, $A^{\cirbd} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** Stix font have also a specific symbol named `\fisheye`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
$a\fisheye b$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use TikZ to build your own:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\ofatdot}{\mathbin{\tikz{\draw[line width=0.25pt] (0,0) circle[radius=0.7ex];\draw[fill] (0,0) circle[radius=0.3ex];}}}
\begin{document}
$a \ofatdot b$
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

As always, this can be improved; in particular, the vertical alignment's not the same as for e. g. `\odot`, which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context (so probably not for the OP, but potentially for others), this symbol is in the International Phonetic Alphabet and represents a bilabial click (aka "kiss"). Hence it is in Unicode, with codepoint U+0298 . Here it is: ʘ

If you use one of the Unicode-ready TeX variants, you can wrap it in a `\mathrel` and you are done.

Comment: This is a bad answer. I wouldn't recommend it at all as the bilabial click isn't supposed to be a circle with a point inside, what you could see with different fonts with IPA support.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "isn't supposed to be a circle with a point inside" -- that _is_ how this IPA symbol is defined. Until I noticed the question's tags ([math-operators] especially), I thought the OP _was_ looking for a phonetic symbol; so I wanted to provide this information for others who will look for it in the future, and arrive here.

Comment: Well, even in that case, the bilabial click as it's actually displayed isn't an actual circle with a dot inside, but I'm not sure whether or not it comes from a stylistic decision.

Comment: Right, I guess it's about as circular as the letter "o". Imagine somebody was looking for a plain letter "o", how would they describe its shape? So *IF* somebody is looking for a letter with these characteristics, then this is certainly the correct solution. For a mathematical operator, probably not.